# Get the value of selected dropdown to compare to another dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have 2 dropdown, the branch dropdown gets app_cn from database. And the sem dropdown gets app_plan_no. But I need to get the value selected in branch dropdown to compare with value selected in sem dropdown.

I saw this code but I don't have any idea how to do this

```
   <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM app GROUP BY app_cn ORDER BY app_cn");
    echo'<select name="drop_1" id="drop_1">';
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
           echo '<option value="'.$row['app_cn'].'">'.$row['app_cn'].'</option>';
        }
echo'</select>';

if($_GET['func'] == "drop_1" && isset($_GET['func'])) {
   drop_1($_GET['drop_var']); 
}

function drop_1($drop_var)
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM app WHERE app_cn='$drop_var' GROUP BY app_plan_no ORDER BY app_plan_no");

    echo '<select name="tier_two" id="tier_two">
          <option value=" " disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose one</option>';

          while($drop_2 = $results->fetch_assoc())
            {
            if($drop_2['app_plan_no'] != '')
            {
              echo '<option value="'.$drop_2['app_plan_no'].'">'.$drop_2['app_plan_no'].'</option>';
            }
            }

}
echo'</select>';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wait_1').hide();
    $('#drop_1').change(function(){
            if( $(this).val() == "ALL") {
            $("#wait_1").hide();
            $("#result_1").hide();
        }else{
      $('#wait_1').show();
      $('#result_1').hide();
      $.get("func.php", {
        func: "drop_1",
        drop_var: $('#drop_1').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_1').fadeOut();
        setTimeout("finishAjax('result_1', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
      });
      }
        return false;
    });
});

function finishAjax(id, response) {
  $('#wait_1').hide();
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
</script>
```

And this what I want to do `WHERE app_cn='$drop_var'`

My table

```
counter | app_cn   | app_plan_no 

000004  |  comp1   |  1
000172  |  comp1   |  1
000007  |  comp1   |  2
000005  |  comp2   |  1
```

And this is my select dropdown

```
<select name="branch" id="branch" onchange="showCourses()">
<option value="ALL" selected='ALL'>ALL</option>
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM app GROUP BY app_cn ORDER BY app_cn");
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
           echo '<option value="'.$row['app_cn'].'">'.$row['app_cn'].'</option>';
        }?>
</select>
<select name="sem" id="sem" onchange="showCourses()">
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM app GROUP BY app_plan_no ORDER BY app_plan_no");
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
           echo '<option value="'.$row['app_plan_no'].'">'.$row['app_plan_no'].'</option>';
        }
        ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of a select statement using jquery use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

To get the value of a select statement when a form is submited using php (serverside) you can find the value of the variable in the $_POST variable where the key is the value of the name attribute for the select statement.

Comment: I tried that, but I don't want to use form. I want to execute with one page.

Comment: It sounds like you want to handle the form? Well then whatever page the form is posting to will have access to all the values the form is submiting in the $_POST variable. If you want to do this on the same page that generates the form you can add an if statement similar to this `if(isset($_POST['tier_two'])){//perform some operations}`

Comment: I post my table. My problem is, dropdown sem echo's all app_plan_no. Just like in my table. comp1 has two app_plan_no, the 1 and 2. And the comp2 does have app_plan_no 1 only. When I choose comp2 in branch dropdown sem dropdown should echo only 1 but it echo also the 2. Because the query in my sem dropdown doesn't have where clause function. Like this WHERE app_cn='$drop_var' . That the problem, I need to get the selected value of branch dropdown to compare to sem dropdown so that it echo only app_plan_no 1 if I choose comp2. Hope you understand what I'm trying to say.